# What is the conventional (and efficient) way to avoid mutability bugs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If you pass a mutable type into a function or method, then inadvertently mutate it inside that function or method, it will also be altered in the outer scope, which can cause pretty bad and hard to find bugs.

What is the industry-accepted way around this when passing in mutable types?

For example, with a list you could use:

```
def func(myList):
    myList = myList[:]
```

And thereafter inside that function `myList` will be a copy that's safe to mutate. Same with using the `copy` module. But is this the best or standard way of doing it?

Or does everyone just reassign all arguments to local scope variables before they do anything else? Kind of an annoying extra step, changing the names of the arguments...

Comment: Access control on object fields, if there is such a thing, and documentation of methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a copy if you need a copy, otherwise don't do anything.  You don't need to reflexively make copies of every argument.  When you write a function, think about what kinds of things are going to be passed in, think about whether you need to mutate those things.  If you do, and you don't want to modify them externally, then make copies.  It's not unheard of to pass in mutable objects that you *do* want to mutate.

In other words, don't look for some all-purposes boilerplate to put at the beginning of every function.  Just consider what each function needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `list()`, because it will take any iterable.

```
def func(iterable):
    myList = list(iterable)
```

Now you can call func with `func(zip(x, y))` and don't have to worry about `zip` not returning a list in Python 3.

Comment: In my mind this solution is only applicable in some scenarios (where the parameter is iterable) and is not very intuitive---

Comment: @Aerovistae: How is it less intuitive than `arg[:]`?

Comment: @Aerovistae `list(x)` will do the same as `x[:]` when `x` is a list, so it is always applicable if `[:]` is.

Comment: For a list, true, but I'm trying to find out if there's any practice that is universally applicable.

Comment: `list()` is as universally applicable as it gets.  It will work whenever `[:]` and in a lot more cases.